# Creating an Amazon S3 bucket Using the AWS SDK for Java v2 : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

Getting below error while trying to create s3 bucket  of aws using java api :

Error :

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/protocols/query/internal/unmarshall/AwsXmlErrorUnmarshaller
                at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorTransformer.<init>(AwsXmlErrorTransformer.java:40)
                at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorTransformer.<init>(AwsXmlErrorTransformer.java:34)
                at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorTransformer$Builder.build(AwsXmlErrorTransformer.java:113)
                at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.AwsXmlProtocolFactory.createErrorTransformer(AwsXmlProtocolFactory.java:135)
                at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.AwsS3ProtocolFactory.createErrorCouldBeInBodyResponseHandler(AwsS3ProtocolFactory.java:80)
                at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.createBucket(DefaultS3Client.java:1144)
                at com.act.niti.main(niti.java:33)
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorUnmarshaller
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
                ... 8 more
```

Code :

```
        try {
         Region region = Region.US_EAST_2; 
         S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .build();
             S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3.waiter();
             CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket("abc")
                    .build();
             
            
             s3.createBucket(bucketRequest); //creating s3 bucket
              System.out.println("bucket........abc");
              HeadBucketRequest bucketRequestWait = HeadBucketRequest.builder()
              .bucket("abc")
              .build();
              
              // Wait until the bucket is created and print out the response
              WaiterResponse<HeadBucketResponse> waiterResponse =
              s3Waiter.waitUntilBucketExists(bucketRequestWait);
              waiterResponse.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
              System.out.println("abc" +" is ready");
             

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Note : Using java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this AWS SDK for Java V2 example and it works fine -- as shown in this screen shot that shows debugging line by line.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Your error looks like missing classes. Did you use the POM dependencies shown in the POM file here?

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3

Comment: Thanks it is working now .it seems i missed some POM dependencies @smac2020

Comment: Glad you have it working

Comment: now with the same code and used all the dependencies but still i am getting the same error mentioned @smac2022